# RobotFramework getting each individual number from a large number

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, robotframework

I'm working on a test case in robotframework. I want to run a so called "11 proef" on a large number.
The number can vary from 8 to 9 numbers. The "11 proef" goes as follows:
number: 005897896
((9 * 0) + (8 * 0) + (7 * 5) + (6 * 8) + (5 * 9) + (4 * 7) + (3 * 8) + (2 * 9)) - 6

So to run this code i need to split the large number in indivual numbers. Is there a way in Robot Framework?

This is wat i have so far:

```
split number
    Create List    @{split-number}
    [arguments]    ${number}
    ${length_number}=    Get Length    ${number}
    FOR    ${letter}    IN RANGE    1    ${length_number+1}
        ${number}=    Fetch From Left    ${number}    ""
        log    ${number}
        Append to list    ${split-number}    ${number}
    END
    return @{split-number}
```

Comment: And does it work? If not, what result are you getting?

Comment: Sadly not. It just prints out the whole number

Answer (score 0):

You can always reside to Python, where such operations might be easier to do.

```py
def split_number(n: str):    
    i = len(n)
    result = 0
    for l in n:
        if i > 1:
            result += (i * int(l))
        else:
            result -= int(l)
        i -= 1
    return result
```

This produces `192` for the number `005897896` from your question.

You can create a custom library and import it into RF. How to do it has been discussed here several times and [it's explained in detail in the official user manual](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries), so I will leave you to it.

Comment: Thank you for youre help! For some reason i couldn't get the custom library to work. But also didn't find the link to the user guide. Thanks i will look in to it

Comment: How do you mean? I included the link to the user guide in my answer, all you need to do is click it and read it and do it as they say.

Comment: Yeah i meant before you send it. But anything did work now. Thanks for helping me!